# JavaScript Anonymous Function Scope Variables

Tags: javascript, html, dom, queryselector

I am a beginner in JS and now learning about DOM manipulations. I'm trying to create an event handler that will print the input string to the console (for example).

When I try to do this, the handler's anonymous function will not recognize the variable:

```
var testThis = document.querySelector('.testInput').value;

document.querySelector('button[id="first"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(testThis); //won't pass the Input to the console
})
```

But when I declare the variable WITHIN the function itself, everything works OK.

So my question is: **shouldnt the function have access to the global scope?**

Thanks!

Comment: Also `"#first"` would be the right selector to use for the `<button>`.

Comment: @Pointy If this were an issue of the script's placement, there would be an error from trying to access `.value` on `null`. The issue is that they're storing the input's _value_ in a variable, so any changes after that would not be reflected.

Comment: @JLRishe ah yea, you're right.

Answer (score 4):

`testThis` will have the value of the input *at the time that first line of code runs*. If someone changes the input's value, and then clicks the button, the variable will still have the old value.

A solution: store the input element itself in a variable, and retrieve its value within the event handler:

```js
var testInput = document.querySelector('.testInput');

document.querySelector('button[id="first"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(testInput.value);
})
```

```html
<input type="text" class="testInput" />
<button id="first">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, but another question was if the anonymous function should have access to the global scope's variables, right? @JLRishe

Comment: @RoyW Yes, it should and does have access to them, as you can observe from my code sample..